# How to select apple default points of interest

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have a question regarding to the default points of interest.

I can show the default POIs using `mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = true`

But I cannot tap on /select those POIs (restaurant, hotel, etc ..). All I want is that when I tap on it, I can get its info (long/lat, name ...)

I tried different delegate methods, such as `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` and `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`but none of those give me the right result

Can anyone help me with it? Thanks :)

Comment: You can't, they're just part of the map they aren't tappable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, from the dev'a position it looks like impossible, but in map app, we can. Therefor I guess, there is maybe a way to do it. I went through the mapkit documents back and forth but can not find any thing useful :(

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Apple doesn't expose POIs to developers. You won't be able to get latitude and longitude, or a callout, from POIs.

You'd be better off using the [Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/), or the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/) to add your own annotations on top of Mapkit.

Comment: This is no longer the case, see WWDC session "What's new in MapKit" from WWDC22

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. You need to set a configuration on the mapView to make points of interest selectable

```
mapView.selectableMapFeatures = [.pointsOfInterest]
```

and then you can listen to when these points are selected by the user using the mapView delegate method

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    print("did select: \(view.description)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in API for selecting those points of interest.  But you can use Google's API for Google maps and it has a lot more things that you can do.

Here is a link to the Google Maps API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I known that google map offer more things to do with map, but right now I prefer to use apple map :)